# Frustrated with view initialization in loadView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller

I do everything programmatically when developing for the ios, so I manually initialize the view controllers view in loadView for all of my view controllers (this is what Apple says to do). What frustrates me about doing it this way is the viewcontrollers frame initially is {{0, 20}, {320, 460}} not correctly accounting for any navbars or tabbars I have in my app. The view finally sets its proper frame in viewDidAppear, but by that time it's too late to do anything. Is there anyway to make it recognize the view layout earlier without having calculate it manually?

It's frustrating because I always have to manually check to see if the phone is in landscape or portrait mode to account for rotation, and if I have to set up my subviews in a specific way that I can't do with autoresizing, then I also have to do manual calculations.

Is there any pattern that apple recommends for doing this, or is there anyway to get it to recognize the view layout earlier without having to calculate it manually?

Comment: Just curious, why do you do everything programmatically?

Comment: you should use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` to get the current size of the view

Comment: I just like to, and a lot of the views im making for my app are dynamic at run time so I need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using iOS 5, you should get passed the correct frame in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` methods of your UIViewController subclass. This is where you should calculate your layout, and they are called when the device rotates.

Otherwise, `viewWillAppear` exists from iOS 2.0, and my test app shows that it is passed the proper frame. It doesn't solve the rotation mid-run, but presumably you can just hook into that elsewhere. You aren't meant to set up your views that late in the game, but other than playing around with `layoutIfNeeded` from `viewDidLoad` (that I didn't manage to get working in the past) I don't know what you are supposed to do pre iOS5.

Comment: Note: these methods only exist from iOS 5.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention, trying to not to use ios 5 libraries want my app to be backwards compatible.

Comment: What about 'viewWillAppear`? That exists from iOS 2.0, and my test app shows that it is passed the proper frame. It doesn't solve the rotation mid-run, but presumably you can hook into that elsewhere.

Comment: viewWillAppear will work, but you're not supposed to set up your views that late in the view controller life cycle. Really supposed to do everything in loadView, populate your views with data in viewDidLoad, and use viewWillAppear, viewDidAPpear for starting threads and animations.

Comment: I agree that you aren't supposed to, but I never worked extensively with pre-5.0 so don't know what you were supposed to use to solve this particular problem. Calling the parent view's `layoutIfNeeded` method from `viewDidLoad` might work; The documentation says it is supposed to lay things out immediately if needed, but I didn't have much luck the one time I tried to use it and solved my problem a different way.

Comment: I don't seem to have any pending edits listed? Either it's not there, I don't have permissions yet (though all guides I read said I should be able to accept edits to my own posts), or it's showing in some non-obvious way (It doesn't say "edit (x)" or anything)... Am I just being stupid?

Comment: I put an edit in there to support your answer, but I guess mods deleted it? I wanted to give yo credit for you said, and just add on to this for people that don't use ios 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure your view has the right autoresizing mask, and it should all adjust once the new size comes in.

```
[view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

That's what I usually do. Otherwise, I adjust the layout in a later callback - it's adjusted for the nav bar by viewWillAppear, not sure if viewDidLoad is too early.